# Import Error Python 2.7. No module named:

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, python-import

I'm receiving an ImportError when running my main script which is related to another script trying to import one of my modules and I'm unsure how to fix it. The layout of the files in relation to the software is as follows (folder names etc are fictional):

```
poetry_generator/main.py

poetry_generator/architecture/experts/poetryexperts/sentence.py

poetry_generator/structures/word.py
```

Main.py is what I'm running, and the problem seems to arise from sentence.py trying to import word module and failing.

Currently in sentence.py I have:

```
from poetry_generator.structures.word import Word
```

Word is the name of the Class in word.py: Class Word(object). But I'm receiving the following error: `ImportError: No module named poetry_generator.structures.word`

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong? I have been readinga roudn similar questions already asked but nothing has worked so far. Thanks in advance for any help.

Full console text reagarding error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from architecture.control_component import ControlComponent
  File "/home/lee/Downloads/PoEmo-master/poetry_generator/architecture/control_component.py", line 4, in <module>
    from experts.poem_making_experts import exclamation_expert
  File "/home/lee/Downloads/PoEmo-master/poetry_generator/architecture/experts/poem_making_experts/exclamation_expert.py", line 5, in <module>
    from poetry_generator.structures.word import Word
ImportError: No module named poetry_generator.structures.word
```

Comment: Do you have a file called `__init__.py` in both `System/` and `structures/`?

Comment: I do, I have these in each of the folders. One with text in. Could this be the problem?

Comment: No, that's a good thing. Are you directly running `sentence.py`, e.g. via `python sentence.py`, or is there another script that you're running as your main program? From what directory are you running your main script?

Comment: My main script is within poetry_generator (which has an init), the word file is within a subdirectory of this folder, and the file I'm importing word into is located within the poetry_Generator folder, then another folder, and then another. So I'm running mani.py in poetry_generator, two subdirectory in is the sentence.py which imports word.py from a different subdirectory of poeytr_generator - if that makes sense. All have inits

Comment: That is difficult to follow in a comment, and it's likely related to your problem. Please edit your question and show the directory structure you just described, identifying the main file.

Comment: Sorry about that, I Wrote the question on my phone without access to the code. I've updated it now. Hopefully clear enough.

Comment: Does `from structures.word import Word` work?

Comment: I noo longer get that error when I run it locally, but I can't run the server anymore -I get the no module error for the django local run now. So I think you may have solved the problem for console but I may have moved on to further problems with the django run haha. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142493/discussion-between-chris-and-djangert).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top-level project directory shouldn't be included in the module name. This should work:

```
from structures.word import Word
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'System/structures/word')
#or
sys.path.append('System/structures/word')

import Word
```

Otherwise you will need `__init__.py` that you can make with [these instructions](https://mikegrouchy.com/blog/be-pythonic-__init__py).

Comment: I'll try this out now, system isn't the actual machine, it was just the name I Was using for the software. I do have initis in each of the folders, but for some reason its just not going.

Comment: I figured about `System`, just wanted to follow your train of thoughts with answer :)

Comment: I've just tried this, if I change "from poetry_generator.structures.word import Word", to "import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'poetry_generator/structures/word')

import Word" I just get an error with no module named Word?

Comment: @zipa: `word` is a file, not a folder, though.

Comment: @SiHa Thanks for comment. `insert` and `append` should go up to folder.

Comment: @zipa: Agreed. `'System/structures/word` is not a valid path, according to OP.

Comment: I've tried altering that as well, and still receiving a no module named Word error. I currently have the following in to try but it isn't working: import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/lee/Downloads/PoEmo-master/poetry_generator/structures')
#or
sys.path.append('/home/lee/Downloads/PoEmo-master/poetry_generator/structures')

import Word

Comment: is `structures` file or folder?

Comment: Structures is a folder within poetry_generator, within poem-master

Comment: did you try `from word import Word` if `word` is name of the file?

Comment: I have, that didn't seem to work eitehr. I've included the full console text regarding the error in the initial question if that helps at all. Thanks so much for the help so far.